# A plethora of unresolved externals when compiling sample Cinder projects

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, unresolved-external, cinder

This is the directory structure for Cinder externals that concerns the question. I don't have any issues with includes, I don't know why I have so many problem with the externals.

```
+---lib
|   
|   +---msw
|   |   +---x86
|   |   |   +---debug
|   |   |   +---release
```

See, inside release there this v120 folder that contains cinder.lib. Now, at first, each project is pointed to externals like this:

```
..\..\..\..\lib\msw\$(PlatformTarget);..\..\..\..\lib\msw\$(PlatformTarget)\$(Configuration)\$(PlatformToolset)
```

But VCS prompts for cinder.lib nonetheless. So I add the subfolder containing the file to the externals path so it finds it, but, amongst one of the many extern symbol errors it generates, "Cannot open file cinder.lib" is one of them. And again, it's not the only one. There's over 20 externs errors for each of the samples, which there are many. I haven't done anything, I'm just trying to compile some samples to learn what the package does, but it keeps generating other errors as well. Would they release their package with buggy code? I don't think so.

The package says it's for VCS 2013. Should I install that instead? I have 2015 Community.

Answer (score 0):

At this time Cinder samples technically supports the v120 compiler so you need that to run the Cinder samples. According to this post on the Cinder forum [link to forum post](https://forum.libcinder.org/topic/anyone-tried-cinder-with-visual-studio-2015) it should work for VCS 2015 but you need to build Cinder for v140 to work.